# Using styled-components in Wordpress Gutenberg save function

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to use [styled-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components)  and other react components on the save() function, but it is not working, the styled-component works just fine on the editor ( edit function ), here is my code for the block:

```
const { __ } = wp.i18n;  
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;

import styled from 'styled-components';


registerBlockType( 'gutenword-blocks/posts', {
    title: 'Styled Div',
    icon: 'admin-page',
    category: 'layout',


    edit: function( props ) {
        const StyledDiv = styled.div`
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
            background: red;
        `;
        return <StyledDiv></StyledDiv>;
    },

    save() {
        const StyledDiv = styled.div`
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
            background: red;
        `;
        return <StyledDiv></StyledDiv>;

    },
} );
```

**Expected behavior**
The block when added should show red square on the editor screen and on the front-end

**Current behavior**
The red square is showing only on the editor and nothing is showing on the frontend

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Unfrouentetly there is no solution for that and here is why? 
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/13743 

As an alternative you can try this solution which has worked for me: 
https://medium.learnreact.com/the-style-tag-and-react-24d6dd3ca974